# z-index is not working with visual composer when position fixed

Tags: html, css

I have created a custom sticky menu on my site but the menu falling behind during scroll with visual composer elements also `z-index` is not working. Please help me what i'm doing wrong ?

You can see the problem [here](http://www.lifetimetech.com/den-pen/)

My CSS

```
.navbar-fixed {
top: 63px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 99999;
overflow: visible;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your sections don't have a position set either.

On an element with the `l-section-h i-cf` class, and a new class with

```
position:relative
z-index:-1
```

Visual example:

[image]

This will also remove the issue of links not being clickable.

Comment: Why The menu item is not clickable ?

Comment: The element is still getting over top the navbar. Taking a look.

Comment: Check my edit. That problem should be resolved if you follow the above.